# Audio input on Mac Mini M1 (2020)

Tags: audio, mac-mini, microphone, apple-silicon

When I connect a microphone to Mac Mini's mini-jack audio out, it does display in `System Preferences > Sound` as "External Microphone", which would suggest it could be used for audio input. However, no "Input level" sound is detected. When I connect the same microphone through a USB adapter (sound card) sound is detected correctly, but I would prefer to use the mini-jack port directly, if possible.

Can Mac Mini (2020) use a mini-jack port for audio input?

[image: Sound settings]

Comment: are you using a stereo microphone (2 rings) or a headset with a microphone (3 rings)? The mac mini only supports 3-ring headsets (mic+headphone) or plain headphones. If your USB adapter has 2 jacks (especially one labeled mic & the other labeled headphone), the dongle supports 2-ring stereo microphones. If you have a headset with 2 headphone jacks, or your microphone is 2-ringed, then you need the USB adapter since the mac only supports 3-ring headsets.

Comment: See https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/ for an explanation of jack varieties